# Adding a prefix to all selectors in a excerpt of CSS with PHP?

Tags: php, css, parsing

Ok so lets say I have a variable `$css` that contains some CSS code. What I want to do is to add a certain text in front of each selector. So for example, the following code:

```
#hello, .class{width:1px;height:1px;background-color:#AAA;}
div{font-size:1px}
input, a, span{padding:4px}
```

Would be converted into:

```
#someId #hello, #someId .class{ ... }
#someId div{ ... }
#someId input, #someId a, #someId span{ ... }
```

I have been trying to use several `explode()`s. However, I haven't been able to accomplish the task effectively. Any thoughts?

Thanks! JCOC611

Comment: Will every CSS rule be on a single line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Jon's suggestion I wrote the following code:

```
<?php

$prefix = '#someId';
$css = '#hello, .class{width:1px;height:1px;background-color:#AAA;}
div{font-size:1px}
input, a, span{padding:4px}';

$parts = explode('}', $css);
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if (empty($part)) {
        continue;
    }

    $subParts = explode(',', $part);
    foreach ($subParts as &$subPart) {
        $subPart = $prefix . ' ' . trim($subPart);
    }

    $part = implode(', ', $subParts);
}

$prefixedCss = implode("}\n", $parts);

echo $prefixedCss;
```

To see that it works see http://codepad.org/bqRd83gu

Comment: What if `@media` or `@font-face` queries are used?

Comment: @Kolink Good point, in those cases this code will not work. But as Jon pointed out, this type of code is a quick and dirty solution to the problem. Luckily it does what JCOC611 needs.

Comment: @Jan-Henk will this work if I need to make sure it only adds if the prefix does not exist already ?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote improved version because I also need media query. This is my function based on Jan's answer:

```
function getPrefixedCss($css,$prefix){
  $parts = explode('}', $css);  
  $mediaQueryStarted = false;
  foreach ($parts as &$part) {
      if (empty($part)) {
          continue;
      }

      $partDetails = explode('{',$part);
      if(substr_count($part,"{")==2){
        $mediaQuery = $partDetails[0]."{";
        $partDetails[0] = $partDetails[1];
        $mediaQueryStarted = true;
      }

      $subParts = explode(',', $partDetails[0]);
      foreach ($subParts as &$subPart) {
          if(trim($subPart)=="@font-face") continue;    
          $subPart = $prefix . ' ' . trim($subPart);
      }       

      if(substr_count($part,"{")==2){
        $part = $mediaQuery."\n".implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2];
      }elseif(empty($part[0]) && $mediaQueryStarted){
        $mediaQueryStarted = false;
        $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2]."}\n"; //finish media query
      }else{
        $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[1];
      }        
  }

  $prefixedCss = implode("}\n", $parts);

  return $prefixedCss;   
}
```

It works with media query and also @font-face.

Answer (score 3):

This is more advanced JohnyFree's variant, with few `dirty` modifications.

This variant packs whole css into a single line,
removes all css comments as well, and checks if `$partDetails[1]` is actually isset at the end, and than goes the imploding *(last `else`)

Give JohnyFree more reputation folks, he deserves it.

ps: I have added `# shell style comments` on places where modifications were performed by me.

```
function getPrefixedCss($css,$prefix)
{
    # Wipe all block comments
    $css = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s', '', $css);

    $parts = explode('}', $css);
    $mediaQueryStarted = false;

    foreach($parts as &$part)
    {
        $part = trim($part); # Wht not trim immediately .. ?
        if(empty($part)) continue;
        else # This else is also required
        {
            $partDetails = explode('{', $part);
            if(substr_count($part, "{")==2)
            {
                $mediaQuery = $partDetails[0]."{";
                $partDetails[0] = $partDetails[1];
                $mediaQueryStarted = true;
            }

            $subParts = explode(',', $partDetails[0]);
            foreach($subParts as &$subPart)
            {
                if(trim($subPart)==="@font-face") continue;
                else $subPart = $prefix . ' ' . trim($subPart);
            }

            if(substr_count($part,"{")==2)
            {
                $part = $mediaQuery."\n".implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2];
            }
            elseif(empty($part[0]) && $mediaQueryStarted)
            {
                $mediaQueryStarted = false;
                $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2]."}\n"; //finish media query
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($partDetails[1]))
                {   # Sometimes, without this check,
                    # there is an error-notice, we don't need that..
                    $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[1];
                }
            }

            unset($partDetails, $mediaQuery, $subParts); # Kill those three ..
        }   unset($part); # Kill this one as well
    }

    # Finish with the whole new prefixed string/file in one line
    return(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',implode("} ", $parts)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a proper CSS parser in order to be able to tell where is the start of each selector.

However, you might be able to get away with a quick and dirty solution by considering that `}` signals the end of each selector, and inserting the necessary text after each occurrence of the closing brace except the last one.

Comment: The flaw of your solution would be rules that have several selectors separated with commas. I'm gonna search for some parsers; by any chance, do you know if *QueryPath* can parse it?

Comment: @JCOC611: Indeed. I can't answer for QueryPath, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This method will add prefixes to all selectors.

```php
/**
 * Prefix CSS code.
 * 
 * @param  $prefix prefix to add to all selectors.
 * @param  $css    CSS code to prefix.
 * @return CSS     the prefixed CSS
 */
function prefixCSS($prefix, $css) {
    $parts = explode('}', $css);
    foreach ($parts as &$part) {
        if (empty($part)) {
            continue;
        }

        $firstPart = substr($part, 0, strpos($part, '{') + 1);
        $lastPart = substr($part, strpos($part, '{') + 2);
        $subParts = explode(',', $firstPart);
        foreach ($subParts as &$subPart) {
            $subPart = str_replace("\n", '', $subPart);
            $subPart = $prefix . ' ' . trim($subPart);
        }

        $part = implode(', ', $subParts) . $lastPart;
    }

    $prefixedCSS = implode("}\n", $parts);

    return $prefixedCSS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for solution guys.
The only thing that was missing for me was keyframes support.
Here is my addition for it:

```
function getPrefixedCss($css,$prefix)
{
    # Wipe all block comments
    $css = preg_replace('!/\*.*?\*/!s', '', $css);

    $parts = explode('}', $css);
    $keyframeStarted = false;
    $mediaQueryStarted = false;

    foreach($parts as &$part)
    {
        $part = trim($part); # Wht not trim immediately .. ?
        if(empty($part)) {
            $keyframeStarted = false;
            continue;
        }
        else # This else is also required
        {
            $partDetails = explode('{', $part);

            if (strpos($part, 'keyframes') !== false) {
                $keyframeStarted = true;
                continue;
            }

            if($keyframeStarted) {
                continue;
            }

            if(substr_count($part, "{")==2)
            {
                $mediaQuery = $partDetails[0]."{";
                $partDetails[0] = $partDetails[1];
                $mediaQueryStarted = true;
            }

            $subParts = explode(',', $partDetails[0]);
            foreach($subParts as &$subPart)
            {
                if(trim($subPart)==="@font-face") continue;
                else $subPart = $prefix . ' ' . trim($subPart);
            }

            if(substr_count($part,"{")==2)
            {
                $part = $mediaQuery."\n".implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2];
            }
            elseif(empty($part[0]) && $mediaQueryStarted)
            {
                $mediaQueryStarted = false;
                $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[2]."}\n"; //finish media query
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($partDetails[1]))
                {   # Sometimes, without this check,
                    # there is an error-notice, we don't need that..
                    $part = implode(', ', $subParts)."{".$partDetails[1];
                }
            }

            unset($partDetails, $mediaQuery, $subParts); # Kill those three ..
        }   unset($part); # Kill this one as well
    }

    # Finish with the whole new prefixed string/file in one line
    return(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',implode("} ", $parts)));
}
```